# Making a date mask react with javascript: If i press simultaneous numbers i lost the mask

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a mask react date dd/mm/yyyy to a custom date input.

If i press the keys slow, the mask is setted correct dd/mm/yyyy, but supposing i press the numbers rapid, my mask is breaking

This is my component:

```
<DateInput
       name="date"
       placeholder="Data"
       value={this.props.data}
       dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
       onChange={this.props.changeDataTarefa}
       animation="none"
       onKeyUp={() => this.props.changeDataTarefaMask(this.fixDatePattern(this.props.data))}/>
```

this is my functions:

```
fixDatePattern(currDate) {
    var currentDate = currDate;
    if (currentDate){
        var currentLength = currentDate.length;
        var lastNumberEntered = currentDate[currentLength - 1];
    }

    if (!this.isNumber(lastNumberEntered) && currentDate) {
      return currentDate.substring(0, currentLength - 1);
    }

    if (currentLength > 10) {
      return currentDate.substring(0, 10);
    }
    let dateCountTracker = 0

    if (currentLength == 1 && currentDate > 1) {
      var transformedDate = "0" + currentDate + '/';
      dateCountTracker = 2;
      currentLength = transformedDate.length;
      return transformedDate;
    } else if (currentLength == 4 && currentDate[3] > 3) {
      let transformedDate = currentDate.substring(0, 3) + "0" + currentDate[3] + '/';
      dateCountTracker = 5;
      currentLength = transformedDate.length;
      return transformedDate;
    } else if (currentLength == 2 && (dateCountTracker != 2 && dateCountTracker != 3)) {
      dateCountTracker = currentLength;
      return currentDate + '/';
    } else if (currentLength == 5 && (dateCountTracker != 5 && dateCountTracker != 6)) {
      dateCountTracker = currentLength;
      return currentDate + '/';
    }

    dateCountTracker = currentLength;
    return currentDate;
  }

isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `keyup`, use `keypress` event on input. And you could also use react input mask plugin for same.

You can use below code for key press event and please check working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/imaskjs-date) demo.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>Date : </span>
        <input type="text" maxLength="10" placeHolder="dd/mm/yyyy" onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress}/>
      </div>
    )
}

 onKeyPress(e){
    let input = e.target;
    if(e.charCode < 47 || e.charCode > 57) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    var len = input.value.length;

    if(len !== 1 || len !== 3) {
      if(e.charCode == 47) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }

    if(len === 2) {
      input.value += '/';
    }

    if(len === 5) {
      input.value += '/';
    }
 }
```

You could use below react input mask plugins to achieve requirement.

[imaskjs](https://imask.js.org/) and [react-input-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-mask)